# Function with a variable number of parameters without any explicit parameters

Tags: c++, function

How to work in C++ with functions the following form: `void function(...) {}`?

Do really need at least one implicit parameter?

Comment: You need at least one parameter. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I highly advise against C variadic functions in C++.

Comment: "You need at least one parameter" - it's part of official standart? It's theoretical question.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function

Comment: @QueueOverflow, Yes, it needs one parameter before the ellipsis so it can use it to reference where the variadic arguments begin.

Comment: You can't think of it as coming "before" the `...` in the argument list. It just magically appears.

Comment: OK, I will keep in mind. Thanks for answer!

Comment: @BoBTFish It doesn't appear "magically". It's being put on the stack in exactly the same manner as all other parameters...

Comment: Yes, but The Standard says nothing about that. And anyway, who says function arguments are always passed on the stack? What about registers? And you still don't know that it will be treated as the "first" parameter. I recall reading somewhere that it is often treated as the "last", but I can't find a reference, so I may be lying.

Comment: **WARNING! REALLY BAD IDEA AHEAD!** Well, who'ld have thunk it! https://ideone.com/WSvDJd

Comment: BoBTFish, nice, it's interesting trick.

Comment: And while we're at it, [more than you could ever possibly want to know about calling conventions](http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf).

Comment: Was just trying the same thing under CL 10, but it doesn't compile ;\ (error C2102: '&' requires l-value) - va_list uses `reinterpret_cast` to `const char&`.

Comment: @BartoszKP, @BoBTFish, I've worked on architectures where the `this` pointer was always passed in a register.

Comment: It seems there is an interesting difference between C99 and C++11 here: C++11 allows a function declaration `void foo(...)` because the *parameter-declaration-list* in the *parameter-declaration-clause* is optional [dcl.fct]/3. In C99, this declaration is **not** allowed since the *parameter-list* is **not** optional in the *parameter-type-list* 6.7.5.

Comment: @DyP Look closer (C++11). It is not optional in the `...` case.

Comment: @BoBTFish All that says is that `void foo(, ...)` is not legal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Repeating from a comment:

It seems there is an interesting difference between C99 and C++11 here: C++11 allows a function declaration `void foo(...)` because the *parameter-declaration-list* in the *parameter-declaration-clause* is optional: [dcl.fct]

Function declaration:

> `D1 (` *parameter-declaration-clause* `)` *cv-qualifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> ref-qualifier<sub>opt</sub> exception-specification<sub>opt</sub> attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>*

Parameters:

> *parameter-declaration-clause:* 
>     *parameter-declaration-list<sub>opt</sub>* `...`<sub>*opt*</sub> 
>     *parameter-declaration-list* `, ...`

(Note how both the *parameter-declaration-list* and the `...` are separately *opt* here, meaning you can leave out one or the other or both. This interpretation is supported by clang++ and g++.)

In C99, this declaration is not allowed since the *parameter-list* is not optional in the *parameter-type-list*: 6.7.5/1

Function declaration:

> *direct-declarator* `(` *parameter-type-list* `)`

Parameters:

> *parameter-type-list:*
>     *parameter-list*
>     *parameter-list* `, ...`

As the `va_start` etc. macros/functions are inherited from C99, there's no way to use the arguments matched with the ellipsis with an empty *parameter-declaration-list* in C++.

---

Description of `va_start` in C99: 7.15.1.4

> `void va_start(va_list ap,`*parmN*`);` 
>   [...] 
>   The parameter *parmN* is the identifier of the rightmost parameter in the variable
>   parameter list in the function definition **(the one just before the `, ...`)**. [...]

Emphasis mine. C99 *assumes* there's a parameter before the ellipsis, because it isn't legal in C99 to declare a function with an ellipsis but without parameters.

---

Yet, I can see two reasons to use a function with an ellipsis but w/o any parameters in C++:

- Overload resolution. Matching arguments to an ellipsis leads to a very low ranking of the overload: An ellipsis conversion sequence is worse than any user-defined and standard conversion sequence [over.ics.rank]/2. This can be useful for metaprogramming:

  ```
  char foo(int);
  int  foo(...);

  struct S{};
  S s;
  sizeof(foo(42));    // yields 1
  sizeof(foo(s));     // yields sizeof(int)
  ```
- Implementation-defined tricks. Your implementation may provide a mean to access those arguments matched with an ellipsis. E.g. see [BobTFish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1171191/bobtfish)'s [example](https://ideone.com/WSvDJd)

Comment: @BoBTFish Oops! Good catch!

Comment: Thanks for such full answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maintain some semblance of platform independence, you need at least one parameter and use the va_arg macros.

If you know the low level details of the architecture and calling convention, then you can pull the arguments directly out of the registers and/or stack (depending on where the various parameters end up).

Answer (score 1):

Given that the `va_start` "function" requires an argument to set up the `va_list`, I'd say it's not possible to do this in a way that works reliably and portably. It may well be possible to find something that works on specific platforms - but don't expect it to work if you change the compiler, compile for a different platform, and in some cases even if you compile with different compiler options (or change the code in the function, e.g. introducing local variables).

```
... 
va_list vl;
va_start(vl, arg);
...
```

Of course, your other problem is knowing when there is NO arguments (which would be a valid case). So if you don't have at least one argument, what happens when you pass no argument at all? How do you "know" this is the case?